# Rewrite requests from loopback to angular2 (Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable)

Tags: angular, loopback

I am using loopback as a backend api and angular2 as a frontend.

I am using loopback to also serve my angular2 frontend.

This works fine, however, once I refresh a page, loopback does not know how to handle the url because this is angular's job, not loopback.

So I get this error :

[image]

I understand 100% why I get this error, because once loopback loads my index.html, then angular2 is bootstrapped and knows how to handle those type of URLs because this is specified in my app.routing.ts file. However, when this link is directly accessed, angular2 is not bootstrapped and loopback does not know how to handle this type of URL.

So I have added code in my loopback code in server.js to redirect all requests to angular except /api that I use for loopback.

Here is the code :

```
var path = require('path');

var ignoredPaths = ['/api'];

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  //Redirecting to index only the requests that do not start with ignored paths
  if(!startsWith(req.url, ignoredPaths))
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'client') });
  else
    next();
});

function startsWith(string, array) {
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if(string.startsWith(array[i]))
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

This works, however, the index.html page is not loaded and I get the following console errors :

```
Refused to execute script from 

'http://localhost:3000/inline.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
59074ce…:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/polyfills.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
59074ce…:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/scripts.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
59074ce…:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/styles.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
59074ce…:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
59074ce…:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I understand the error, but dont know why i am receiving this and dont know how to fix this.

This is my middleware.json file for my loopback backend:

```
{
  "initial:before": {
    "loopback#favicon": {}
  },
  "initial": {
    "compression": {},
    "cors": {
      "params": {
        "origin": true,
        "credentials": true,
        "maxAge": 86400
      }
    },
    "helmet#xssFilter": {},
    "helmet#frameguard": {
      "params": [
        "deny"
      ]
    },
    "helmet#hsts": {
      "params": {
        "maxAge": 0,
        "includeSubdomains": true
      }
    },
    "helmet#hidePoweredBy": {},
    "helmet#ieNoOpen": {},
    "helmet#noSniff": {},
    "helmet#noCache": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "session": {},
  "auth": {},
  "parse": {
    "body-parser#json": {},
    "body-parser#urlencoded": {"params": { "extended": true }}
  },
  "routes": {
    "loopback#rest": {
      "paths": [
        "${restApiRoot}"
      ]
    }
  },
  "files": {
    "loopback#static": {
      "params": "$!../client/"
    }
  },
  "final": {
    "loopback#urlNotFound": {}
  },
  "final:after": {
    "strong-error-handler": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to play around with the helmet options by disabling some of the security just to see if it will work but I still get the sameissues.

Comment: Do not mark a question as "solved" manually. Instead you should mark an answer as "accepted".

Comment: @crashmstr ok, I will in 2 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [angular.io docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/deployment.html#!#server-configuration), **"Routed apps must fallback to index.html"**. This means that if loopback cannot "GET" or result in any type of 404, it means that loopback does not understand the url and it needs to "fallback" to the index.html of the angular2 or angular4 app.

To fix this, you will have to add custom middleware to redirect loopback to your angular index so that angular's router can take it from there.

So in your **middleware.json** file, change the following :

```
"final": {
    "./middleware/custom404": {}
    }
```

Then add a file custom404.js inside /server/middleware/ so that the full path is **/server/middleware/custom404.js** . If the middleware directory does not exist, create it.

Then inside the **custom404.js** file :

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function () {
    var path = require('path');
    return function urlNotFound(req, res, next) {
        let angular_index = path.resolve('client/index.html');
        res.sendFile(angular_index, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.status(err.status).end();
            }
        });
    };
};
```

This will redirect back to your angular app and angular's router will route the url correctly while still being served by loopback.

## Important

It is therefore no longer needed to redirect the app via server.js as I tried to do in the opening question above !